# Why Hashtable's load factor is not consistent with the one described in CLRS book?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable, clrs

From the doc of Java about Hashtable class, it says

> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff between time and space costs

So the load factor for Hashtable is 0.75, which means if there are N keys, Hashtable will use M = N/0.75 spaces to store them.

In CLRS book, it also introduces load factor alpha.

But from my understanding, CLRS intends to set alpha larger than 1, i.e., M = N/alpha < N. This means a Hashtable can use M slots where M < N so that it can save storage from unused keys.

I say M < N can save storage because normally we don't know exactly value for N, but we know the set of the keys and use N to stand for possible number of keys. The set of the keys may be very big, but the number of actual keys in use is very small. So setting M smaller than N can save the storage. Also this is why normally Hashtable does not use a direct array to map every {key, value} 1:1.

But Hashtable in Java use storage more than N. I think it is not consistent with the CLRS design, right?

Am I right?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the load factor should be larger than the elements added. Division by a number less than one results in a larger number than the initial one.

Assuming you want to add 100 elements you can write either:

```
AllocationSize = 100 / 0.75; // Your formula: M = N/0.75
```

or

```
AllocationSize = 100 * 1.33333333; // M = N / X -> M = N * (1/X)
```

where both results in `133.333333` -> `133`.

The whole JavaDoc:

> An instance of Hashtable has two parameters that affect its
>   performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the
>   number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is
>   simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. Note that
>   the hash table is open: in the case of a "hash collision", a single
>   bucket stores multiple entries, which must be searched sequentially.
>   The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to
>   get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of
>   entries in the hashtable exceeds the product of the load factor and
>   the current capacity, the capacity is increased by calling the rehash
>   method.
>
> Generally, the default load factor (.75) offers a good tradeoff
>   between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the space
>   overhead but increase the time cost to look up an entry (which is
>   reflected in most Hashtable operations, including get and put).
>
> The initial capacity controls a tradeoff between wasted space and the
>   need for rehash operations, which are time-consuming. No rehash
>   operations will ever occur if the initial capacity is greater than the
>   maximum number of entries the Hashtable will contain divided by its
>   load factor. However, setting the initial capacity too high can waste
>   space.
>
> If many entries are to be made into a Hashtable, creating it with a
>   sufficiently large capacity may allow the entries to be inserted more
>   efficiently than letting it perform automatic rehashing as needed to
>   grow the table.

Comment: Yeah, I know the calculations. My question is why it sets allocationsSize bigger than N? I think one point for Hashtable not using direct array mapping is to save storage. But setting allocationSize bigger than N is a waste, right?

Comment: The `whole` javadoc about HashMap offers much more information as you selected. making N larger than 1 is nonsense. The access time will be slowed down extremely and the whole HashMap will be "useless".

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of the CLRS book, but I can tell you using a load factor of more then about 0.75 (even less for some hash map designs) leads to a significant number of collisions.

If you allow the HashMap or Hashtable to grow naturally, its capacity will be proportional to the number of entries. These references are small (typically 4 bytes) compared to the size of Entry objects (typically 16 - 24 bytes) so the hash index table you are concerned about will always be several times smaller than the size of the Entry objects, let alone the keys and values.